# Pre Increment and end of string

Tags: c++, string, pre-increment

Suppose I have this code section

```
char *ptr[] = {"Hi", "Alexa"};
  std::cout<<++*ptr<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<++*ptr<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<++*ptr<<std::endl;
  std::cout<<++*ptr<<std::endl;
```

The out put is

> ```
> i
>
> Alexa
> lexa
> ```

Why is there a space between "i" and "Alexa"? And if I change" endl" to "\n", there won't be any space.

Comment: You have out of bound access hense UB. It is quite pointless to discuss your code behaviour - it is undefined.

Comment: Wow, I would not have guessed that `++*ptr` would increment the pointer and not the character.

Comment: I'm not convinced you understand what `++*ptr` is actually doing. It would improve you question *tremendously* if you noted why you're doing that in your code, and your expectations from said-same. Also, that code should flag at-least warnings with any decent C++ compiler, as both of those literals are read-only, and you setting up an array of non-const hot pointers to them.

Comment: @MarkRansom array of pointers. `*ptr` = first pointer, not first character of first pointer.

Comment: @WhozCraig yeah, I just figured that out too. Makes this question even crazier.

Comment: @WhozCraig I'm just trying to understand how the operator ++ works with a pointer. Suppose I want to move to the next element of the array, then how can the operator help me to do it? I'm using an online compiler on my phone right now so I suppose It could cause things that normal compilers wouldn't

Comment: "I'm just trying to understand how the operator ++ works" running random code is not the best way to understand how things work, especially in C++. Very often you will learn how things do not work, but you have no way to know they actually don't.

Answer (score 3):

`""` (`{'\0'}`) is valid string, an empty string.

the `Alexa` is printed probably because compiler put it just after `"hi"`, but it's undefined behavior.

possible memory layout :
`{ h, i, \0, A, l, e, x, a, \0 }`

---

```
i     // "hi"+1 -> {'i','\0'}
      // "hi"+2 -> {'\0'}, empty string
Alexa // UB, just incidentally it's place there by compiler
lexa  // UB, just incidentally it's place there by compiler
```

Comment: Where did the `i` go to or come from in the first line of your code snippet? And, now (third or fourth edit?) where's the backslash in the first line of your post.

Comment: @AdrianMole `*ptr` is a pointer to "hi" (char*) so increase it point to "i" (although it should be `const char*`)

Comment: But you have `{'h','\0'}` ... shouldn't that be `{'i','\0'}` ?

Comment: @AdrianMole fixed, it should be `i` :P

Comment: That's the trouble with posting fast answers ... mistakes happen and the question gets closed while you're trying to fix them.

Comment: @AdrianMole edits to an answer are still allowed even if the question is closed.

Comment: @AdrianMole I'm not sure what you mean. a typo happened whether I type it fast or slow. And I think the intent is pretty clear as very first sentence. (btw the dupes doesn't show why there is empty line, which is no UB (at it's own) )

Comment: @Mark Indeed. That doesn't mean the question is not a duplicate, though. However, *maybe* it isn't actually a duplicate, because the space/blank line happens before the UB.

Comment: That memory layout is probably not accidental, but you're right in calling out UB.

Comment: @AdrianMole unfortunately SO is influencing fast answers. I've seen many examples people post placeholder and then edit it to real answer.

Comment: @Slava Yes, I know. In this case, though the edit history doesn't show it, there were lots of separate edits (maybe 6 or 7) - mostly made within the "grace period" of each other.

Comment: And why change `accident` (correct) to `incident` (not correct)?

Comment: @AdrianMole the undefined behavior isn't restricted to after the code that triggers it. One of my favorite posts on UB: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633

Comment: @MarkRansom incident, not very good at english :) If there is other function using the string, compiler would probably put them away.

Comment: @AdrianMole not good at English, I'd like to say not deterministic and no harm, is there a good way?

Comment: OK - You can use "by accident" or "incidentally" I suppose. But not "by incident".